Anaconda Navigator Cannot initalize GLX
I use Fedora Nobara. I made an update to Nobara 40. Before that anaconda navigator was working perfectly and now it gives me this error
> conda activate TheWorld 
> anaconda-navigator              
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSize 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
Could not initialize GLX
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  anaconda-navigator

I can't filter it down to which is the real cause for this issue. And took the basic measures still having the same issue.
How to resolve this?

I’m using Arch Linux and encountered an issue after upgrading Anaconda Navigator. I reinstalled both Anaconda and Navigator, but it didn’t help. Here’s the error I got when trying to run Anaconda Navigator:
2024-10-17 14:18:25,806 - WARNING    linux_scaling.get_scaling_factor_using_dbus:32                                                                                                               
An exception occurred during fetching list of system display settings.                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                               
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSi
ze 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile 
 QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)                                                                                                                                                                    
qt.glx: qglx_findConfig: Failed to finding matching FBConfig for QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize -1, redBufferSize 1, greenBufferSi
ze 1, blueBufferSize 1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize -1, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::SingleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile 
 QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)                                                                                                                                                                    
Could not initialize GLX                                                                                                                                                                       
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)

Steps that solved the above for me:

conda update anaconda-navigator

The command produced the below output
Channels:                                                                                                                                                                                      
- defaults                                                                                                                                                                                    
Platform: linux-64                                                                                                                                                                             
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done                                                                                                                                              
Solving environment: done                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                               
# All requested packages already installed.

The final command:

export QT_XCB_GL_INTEGRATION=none

I also changed the following flag in ~/.anaconda/navigator/anaconda-navigator.ini
enable_high_dpi_scaling = True
                                                                                                                         

